# Building a 4’ picket fence with steel posts?

Tags: fence, post

I’m prepping to build a 4’ wood picket fence in our yard. I’ve been seeing a lot of blogs and videos about using steel posts instead of 4x4s for wood fences for better durability. most of them seem to be referring to 6-8’ privacy fences. Just wondering if there’s any reason not to do that for my smaller fence or if anyone has done it before?

Comment: Should be able to do it with steel fence posts.  Only main problem is that they usually only have about an inch wide face for attaching to and usually use wire instead of nails/screws.  Could tie a board to them first and mount fence to board.  Nice thing about steel posts is no digging, just pound them into ground.

Comment: Maybe edit your question on type of steel post.  I am thinking of farm T post type but you might want round pipe type posts.